# Column specifiers in CQ5 XPath query

Tags: xpath, aem

I am trying to get a list of pages in CQ 5.4, modified after a certain date along with information when a page was modified and by who

So long I have created a XPath query to find all pages modified after a certain date:

```
/jcr:root/path/to/portal//element(*, cq:Page)[
(@jcr:content/cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00'))
] order by jcr:content/@cq:lastModified descending
```

Running it in CRXDE This gives me only the list of pages like:

```
/path/to/portal/page1
/path/to/portal/page4
/path/to/portal/page2
```

I would need to display also values of cq:lastModified, cq:lastModifiedBy. Preferably to be displayed as:

```
/path/to/portal/page1 | user1 | YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00
/path/to/portal/page4 | user1 | YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00
/path/to/portal/page2 | user2 | YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00
```

I have tried column specifiers like:

```
/jcr:root/path/to/portal//element(*, cq:Page)/(@cq:lastModifiedBy | @cq:lastModified)[
(@jcr:content/cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00'))
] order by jcr:content/@cq:lastModified descending
```

But it gets me nothing.

Is there a way of running this query in CQ to get me the results I need?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code you used to access the QueryResult.

In theory, `QueryResult.getRows().nextRow().getValues()` returns a `Value[]` in the same order as `QueryResult.getColumnNames()`.

In practice, a query returns iterators for Resources or Nodes - and you can adapt these to ValueMap to get individual properties out.  I wrote a blog post on the different types of queries at http://itgumby.github.io/blog/2014/10/cq-queries-demystified/ that shows JSP code examples for accessing query results.

If using a language like groovy, you can simplify result manipulation to:

```
String query = "/jcr:root/path/to/portal//element(*, cq:Page)/(@cq:lastModifiedBy | @cq:lastModified)[(@jcr:content/cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+02:00'))] order by jcr:content/@cq:lastModified descending"
Collection<Resource> results = resourceResolver.findResources(query, Query.XPATH).collect { it as Resource }
results.each { rsc ->
    def props = rsc.adapTo(ValueMap)
    String path = rsc.path
    String user = props.get('jcr:content/cq:lastModifiedBy', '')
    String lastMod = props.get('jcr:content/cq:lastModified', '')
    // do what you need with path/user/lastMod
}
```

Further, if you changed from `cq:Page` to `cq:PageContent`, you can remove the `jcr:content/` from subsequent access.